# Test our SAML Identity Provider software?

Tags: identity, provider, saml

We run siteminder as our SSO solution.  We will be using its SAML capabilities to authorize people for a 3rd party (we will be the Identity Provider).  Is there an opensource piece of software I can install that will allow me to set up SAML and test our Identity Provider setup?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely suggest using SimpleSAMLPHP (http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.9/simplesamlphp-sp)

You could also use a Google Apps for Business service as a SAML service provider as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to take a look at http://www.testshib.org.

You can host your IdP server on a machine that has a global DNS, then config your IdP at testshib.org. Then it will have a SP to connect to you.